# Carousel Material 3 design Corner Radius Kotlin Xml

Tags: android, kotlin, carousel, material3

I am working on an Android app where I'm trying to create a carousel using the Material Components library. Each carousel item is a `MaskableFrameLayout` containing an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. However, I'm facing an issue where the image being displayed  is not round in the layout.

Here's the relevant part of my XML layout code for the carousel item:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.carousel.MaskableFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/carousel_item_container"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:shapeAppearance="?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerExtraLarge">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/carousel_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/nature" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nametext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:text="Name "
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.carousel.MaskableFrameLayout>
```